# Sum of an array from json data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hi guys im having trouble bringing back the sum of an array from a json api.
im able to select the json data and select the grades only. my plan was ... once i have the grades to use the reduce method to get the sum of each array and then divide by the length. so as you can see it didnt work out , infact it brings me some strange number which looks like the total of all the numbers in each array divided by the length of each array. i tried every single way to do it for loop etc . its not the for loop or the method im using that doesnt work, its the way im bringing down the array or atleast the way my reduce method is calculating the arrays. so how do i get the sum of each array individually? theres 25 arrays so ill need 25 sums. i placed the code down here below. or above ...

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { Input } from "@material-ui/core";

function StudentProfiles()  {

    const [info, setInfo] = useState();
    const [input, setInput] = useState('');
    const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);
    const [Average, setAverage] = useState([]);
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        
         fetch("https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => setInfo(json.students))
    },[]);
    
    
    
    const filterChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const target = e.target.value;
        setInput(target);

        if(input !== '') {
            const result = info && info.filter((user) => {
                return user.firstName.toLowerCase().startsWith(input.toLowerCase()); 
            });
            setFiltered(result);
        } if(input !== '') {
            const result = info && info.filter((person) => {
                return person.lastName.toLowerCase().startsWith(input.toLowerCase()); 
            });
            setFiltered(result);
        } else {
             setFiltered(info);
        }
    }
      
         const gradePopulate = () => {
                 info && info.map((grades) => {
                    const listGrades = grades.grades;
                    setAverage(listGrades);
                   var  a=0;
                    const p = Average.reduce((a,b) => a + b , a);
                    console.log(p);
                    });
             
         }

    return (
        <div>
            <Card className="card">
                <CardContent className="scrollbar scrollbar-primary mt-5 mx-auto">
                    <Input
                    className="searchBar"
                    icon="search"
                    placeholder="Search by name"
                    onChange={filterChange}
                    value={input}
                    />
                    {filtered.map((name) => (
                        <ul className = "border" key={name.id}>
                            <Grid item xs={3} sm={6} md={12} style={{display: "flex", gap:"3.5rem", paddingBottom:"8px"}}>
                                <img alt ="" src={name.pic} className="picture"></img> 
                                <Grid  container style={{display: "inline"}} align="left" justifyContent="flex-end" alignItems="flex-start">
                                    <Grid  className="studentNames">
                                    <span>{name.firstName + " " + name.lastName}</span>
                                    <Grid container align="right" justifyContent="flex-end" alignItems="flex-end" style={{display: "inline"}} >
                                        <button  onClick={gradePopulate} className="plus"></button></Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <span>{name.email}</span>
                                    <br/>
                                    <span>{name.company}</span>
                                    <br/>
                                    <span>{name.skill}</span>
                                    <br/>
                                    <span>Average: {9}%</span>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </ul>
                ))}
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </div>
    ) 
}



export default StudentProfiles;
```

Comment: Can you provide us with examples of how your data is structured and how it's returned via the API call for that function you're running?

Comment: So my data is stored in a react hook called "info". In the gradePopulate function I call on the react hook and map through it and pick on grades. then currently i just console.log it. idk what do show you though. its all in the code above tho.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how your data is structured but from your code, I am guessing
`info = [{ grades: [] }, { grades: [] }]`

and you want to sum the grades in each objects. If so, you can change your function to the below.

```js
const store = {students: [{grades: ["78","100","92","86","89","88","91","87"]}, {grades: ["75","89","95","93","99","82","89","76"]}, {grades: ["88","90","79","82","81","99","94","73"]}, {grades: ["88","93","92","81","95","98","77","94"]}, {grades: ["71","81","72","92","79","82","91","90"]}, {grades: ["97","92","72","99","92","92","79","96"]}]};

const info = store.students
const gradePopulate = () => {
      return info && info.map((grades) => {
         const listGrades = grades.grades;
         // setAverage(listGrades);
         const p = listGrades.reduce((a,b) => a + Number(b) , 0);
         return p
      });
             
    }
    
console.log(gradePopulate())
```

```js
 const store = {students: [{grades: ["78","100","92","86","89","88","91","87"]}, {grades: ["75","89","95","93","99","82","89","76"]}, {grades: ["88","90","79","82","81","99","94","73"]}, {grades: ["88","93","92","81","95","98","77","94"]}, {grades: ["71","81","72","92","79","82","91","90"]}, {grades: ["97","92","72","99","92","92","79","96"]}]};

    const info = store.students
    const gradePopulate = () => {
          const totalSum = info.reduce((a, b) => a + b.grades.reduce((c, d) => c + Number(d), 0), 0);
          const totalLength = info.reduce((a, b) => a + b.grades.length, 0)
          return totalSum / totalLength
                          
        }
        
    console.log(gradePopulate())
```

Comment: you mean you want to see the whole json ??? also i did that before but then i think it adds all of the grades and divides by length. so i end up getting some large millionth number.

Comment: yes. or atleast the info array or object.

Comment: https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students .  so right there you can see the whole json.

Comment: Ok then I think the above code should give you the required output. p will be the sum of all the individual arrays.

Comment: If is it helpful mark as answered?

Comment: Do you mean it'll result in 25 array sums? Or one total sum. When I do the entire formula and try to divide by length it results in the wrong answer. The correct answer should land Me at around 86 Something for the first one for example . Instead I get 9747484948 number or something like that .

Comment: When I take the grades out and put them in one single variable stored . Then do length . The answer is correct .but whenever I try to do it through the json it gives me a weird result .

Comment: Yes I mean it will return 25 array sums. I have updated the question. One has code will return array of the sums of each student. I picked 6 usecase so that why it is return 6 element in array. I am also think you want the total average hence the second block. Please try to be clear with what you want to achieve with data and expected result.